# Fastlane Increment build number based on previous build number in test flight

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane, fastfile

I had setup fast lane and everything works fine and the app gets uploaded to test flight using the following fast file. I want to auto increment the build number based on the previous build number in TestFlight and upload new build with that incremented build number. Please advice how to do this

```
class Fastfile: LaneFile {

func customLane() {

    let buildNumber = latestTestflightBuildNumber(appIdentifier: "com.softence.DemoApp", username: "iosapp@dreamapps.com")
    incrementBuildNumber(buildNumber: String(describing: buildNumber + 1))

    buildIosApp(scheme: "DemoApp")
    uploadToTestflight(username: "iosapp@dreamapps.com", teamId: "39941891")
   }
}
```

After execution it again asks to select the team from list of teams. I want to increment the build number and upload the build directly to test flight

Comment: Use `incrementBuildNumber`?

Comment: @Tj3n I have updated my question please check this

Answer (score 1):

On fastlane (2.205.2), this worked for me to get and set the last build from Testflight:

```
current_build_number = app_store_build_number(live: false) //live false means Testflight, true would take the current production build
increment_build_number(xcodeproj: 'path/toyour/project', build_number: current_build_number + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, but could not find anything on how to achieve incrementing build number in the Swift Fastfile. However, I found a work around.

**Note**: I only wanted to increment build number and then push to TestFlight.

**Work around:**

1. Setup Fastlane Swift (I chose the push to Beta setup). Docs [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/).
2. In Terminal, run `fastlane run increment_build_number` to get increment the build number first.
3. After that's done, run `fastlane beta`. This is only if your lane/function in the Fastfile is called `betaLane()`, change it accordingly. If it's called `helloLane()`, then use `fastlane hello`.

**And you're done!**

However, that's two commands, let's make it into one (*optional, but nice*):

1. To wrap this into one command, create a shell script. First, enter into Terminal `vim name_of_script.sh`.
2. Put both commands into your script: `fastlane run increment_build_number; fastlane beta;`
3. Save and run your script!

If you get this error: `Apple Generic Versioning is not enabled in this project` then follow the directions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html) to enable it. It's really easy, just read it.

After all this, you should be able to push to TestFlight with an incremented build number with just one command!